# Why is kworker consuming so many resources on Linux 3.0.0-12-server?

Tags: kernel, performance, cpu, load

Last Friday I upgraded my Ubuntu server to 11.10, which now runs with a 3.0.0-12-server kernel. Since then the overall performance has dropped dramatically. Before the upgrade the system load was about 0.3, but currently it is at 22-30  on an 8 core CPU system with 16GB of RAM (10GB free, no swap used).

I was going to blame the BTRFS file system driver and the underlaying MD array, because [md1_raid1] and [btrfs-transacti] consumed a lot of resources. But all the [kworker/*:*] consume a lot more.

`sar` has outputted something similar to this constantly since Friday:

```
11:25:01        CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle 
11:35:01        all      1,55      0,00     70,98      8,99      0,00     18,48 
11:45:01        all      1,51      0,00     68,29     10,67      0,00     19,53 
11:55:01        all      1,40      0,00     65,52     13,53      0,00     19,55 
12:05:01        all      0,95      0,00     66,23     10,73      0,00     22,10
```

And `iostat` confirms a very poor write rate:

```
sda             129,26      3059,12       614,31  258226022   51855269          
sdb              98,78        24,28      3495,05    2049471  295023077          
md1             191,96       202,63       611,95   17104003   51656068          
md0               0,01         0,02         0,00       1980        109
```

The question is: How can I track down why the kworker threads consume so many resources (and which one)? Or better: Is this a known issue with the 3.0 kernel, and can I tweak it with kernel parameters?

**Edit:**

I updated the Kernel to the brand new version 3.1 as recommended by the BTRFS developers. But unfortunately this didn't change anything.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/33640/kworker-what-is-it-and-why-is-it-hogging-so-much-cpu. I would add to his suggestions removing kernel modules one at a time to see if it is a specific one.

Comment: @ShawnJ.Goff This is just a workaround provided by trial and error. But I want to know how I can identify the culprit with some (debugging) tools. This should then lead me to a kernel module in question.

Comment: Try booting with `pcie_ports=compat` or `pcie_ports=native`. (Try 'native' first. It's less likely to fix the problem but less likely to cause other problems.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Didn't change. This would also be just a solution to avoid the problem. But I need to identify the problem myself to then elaborate on a solution. How can I identify the cause?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found [this thread on lkml](https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/3/31/68) that answers your question a little. (It seems even Linus himself was puzzled as to how to find out the origin of those threads.)

Basically, there are two ways of doing this:

```
$ echo workqueue:workqueue_queue_work > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/set_event
$ cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe > out.txt
(wait a few secs)
```

For this you will need [ftrace](http://www.elinux.org/Ftrace) to be compiled in your kernel, and to enable it with:

```
mount -t debugfs nodev /sys/kernel/debug
```

More information on the function tracer facilities of Linux is available in the [ftrace.txt documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt).

This will output what threads are all doing, and is useful for tracing multiple small jobs.

```
cat /proc/THE_OFFENDING_KWORKER/stack
```

This will output the stack of a single thread doing a lot of work. It may allow you to find out what caused this specific thread to hog the CPU (for example). `THE_OFFENDING_KWORKER` is the pid of the kworker in the process list.

Comment: Thanks.  I had to repeatedly cat the stack file until it got long enough to provide some info.  In my case, I found "acpi_ds_create_operands" and "input_polled_device_work".  A lucky guess made me try the `-E` option to sleepd, and the CPU usage disappeared!

Answer (score 5):

The solution is: I don't know how to find the cause. Nobody told me so far.

But talking with the BTRFS developers revealed a bug in the btrfs drivers when writing many many small files in a very short time period. This is an issue on kernels from 3.0 upto 3.1. Maybe it gets fixed in 3.2.

In the meantime I got a patch for the current kernel that solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue; looking at the kworker's thread stack:

```
while true ; do clear ; grep -n ^ /proc/24910/stack | sort -rn | cut -d: -f 2- ; sleep 1 ; done

[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
[<ffffffff810908f0>] kthread+0x0/0xe0
[<ffffffff81576432>] ret_from_fork+0x42/0x70
[<ffffffff810908f0>] kthread+0x0/0xe0
[<ffffffff810909b1>] kthread+0xc1/0xe0
[<ffffffff8108b520>] worker_thread+0x0/0x550
[<ffffffff8108b573>] worker_thread+0x53/0x550
[<ffffffff8108aa4b>] process_one_work+0x14b/0x420
[<ffffffff81405a3d>] rpm_idle+0x1ad/0x220
[<ffffffff8140509d>] __rpm_callback+0x2d/0xb0
[<ffffffffa01aef16>] usb_runtime_idle+0x26/0x30 [usbcore]
[<ffffffffa01aeef0>] usb_runtime_idle+0x0/0x30 [usbcore]
[<ffffffff8140686c>] __pm_runtime_suspend+0x5c/0x90
[<ffffffff81405b19>] __pm_runtime_idle+0x69/0x90
[<ffffffff81405295>] rpm_suspend+0x105/0x620
[<ffffffff8140513f>] rpm_callback+0x1f/0x70
[<ffffffff8140509d>] __rpm_callback+0x2d/0xb0
[<ffffffffa01aee50>] usb_runtime_suspend+0x0/0x80 [usbcore]
[<ffffffffa01aee7e>] usb_runtime_suspend+0x2e/0x80 [usbcore]
[<ffffffffa01adc4f>] usb_suspend_both+0xef/0x1f0 [usbcore]
[<ffffffffa01adb06>] usb_resume_interface.isra.6+0xa6/0x100 [usbcore]
[<ffffffffa01a0c63>] hub_resume+0x23/0x60 [usbcore]
[<ffffffffa01a0636>] hub_activate+0xc6/0x5c0 [usbcore]
[<ffffffffa01a9d3f>] usb_kill_urb+0x3f/0xa0 [usbcore]
[<ffffffffa019d249>] hub_port_status+0xd9/0x120 [usbcore]
[<ffffffff81088a4f>] __queue_work+0x12f/0x340
[<ffffffff810888b6>] insert_work+0x46/0xb0
[<ffffffffa01aa6d4>] usb_control_msg+0xc4/0x110 [usbcore]
[<ffffffffa01aa55a>] usb_start_wait_urb+0x9a/0x150 [usbcore]
[<ffffffff810a36f7>] update_curr+0xd7/0x120
```

I figured it's the usb modules. I had previously on another machine blithely rmmod'd all usb and [uex]hci modules are realised that I had turned off the keyboard (not even ctrl-shift-sysrq-U !), so I ended up doing this:

```
MODS="uvcvideo ohci_hcd ehci_hcd xhci_hcd ohci_pci ehci_pci xhci_pci usbcore"
( echo $MODS $MODS | xargs -n 1 rmmod -v ; sleep 3 ; echo $MODS | xargs -n 1 modprobe -v ; )

root@hp:~# ( echo $MODS $MODS | xargs -n 1 rmmod -v ; sleep 3 ; echo $MODS | xargs -n 1 modprobe -v ; )
rmmod: ERROR: Module ohci_hcd is in use by: ohci_pci
rmmod: ERROR: Module ehci_hcd is in use by: ehci_pci
rmmod: ERROR: Module xhci_hcd is in use by: xhci_pci
rmmod: ERROR: Module uvcvideo is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module ohci_pci is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module ehci_pci is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module xhci_pci is not currently loaded
insmod /lib/modules/4.1.0-2-amd64/kernel/drivers/media/usb/uvc/uvcvideo.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.1.0-2-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/host/ehci-hcd.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.1.0-2-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/host/ohci-hcd.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.1.0-2-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/host/xhci-hcd.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.1.0-2-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/host/ehci-pci.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.1.0-2-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/host/ohci-pci.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.1.0-2-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/host/xhci-pci.ko
```

did the trick:

```
grep -n ^ /proc/24910/stack | sort -rn | cut -d: -f 2-
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
[<ffffffff810908f0>] kthread+0x0/0xe0
[<ffffffff81576432>] ret_from_fork+0x42/0x70
[<ffffffff810908f0>] kthread+0x0/0xe0
[<ffffffff810909b1>] kthread+0xc1/0xe0
[<ffffffff8108b520>] worker_thread+0x0/0x550
[<ffffffff8108b5ec>] worker_thread+0xcc/0x550
```

So my chief suspect is this gadget:
RTL8723B* WIFI+Bluetooth Module.
I'm wondering now if the power-management code realises it's the same device if it tries to e.g. powerdown an unused BT adapter.

context:

```
root@hp:~# lsusb
    Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0c45:651b Microdia 
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:b001 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

root@hp:~# lsmod | grep usb
    btusb                  45056  0
    btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
    btintel                16384  1 btusb
    bluetooth             438272  5 bnep,btbcm,btusb,btintel
    usbcore               200704  8 btusb,uvcvideo,ohci_hcd,ohci_pci,ehci_hcd,ehci_pci,xhci_hcd,xhci_pci
    usb_common             16384  1 usbcore

root@hp:~# lsb_release -a
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID:    Debian
    Description:    Debian GNU/Linux stable-updates (sid)
    Release:    stable-updates
    Codename:    sid

root@hp:~# uname -a
    Linux hp 4.1.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.1.6-1 (2015-08-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@hp:~# dmesg | tail -n 20
    [97865.088740] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: HP Webcam
    [97865.091557] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HP Webcam (0c45:651b)
    [97865.105948] input: HP Webcam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0/input/input17
    [97865.189817] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 2 using ohci-pci
    [97865.350981] usb 3-3: No LPM exit latency info found, disabling LPM.
    [97865.368958] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=b001
    [97865.368969] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
    [97865.368976] usb 3-3: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
    [97865.368981] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: Realtek 
    [97865.368985] usb 3-3: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
    [97865.375859] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
    [97865.375867] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
    [97865.375896] usb 3-3: firmware: failed to load rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin (-2)
    [97865.375902] usb 3-3: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin failed with error -2
    [97865.375907] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
    [97865.397812] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
    [97865.397821] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
    [97865.397850] usb 3-3: firmware: failed to load rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin (-2)
    [97865.397856] usb 3-3: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin failed with error -2
    [97865.397861] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
```

Answer (score -3):

`echo N >/sys/module/drm_kms_helper/parameters/poll`
(in root mode)

Problem with Intel graphic card

Comment: How do you know that that is the cause?